# Loading and Saving C++ torch model in Python and another OS

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, pytorch, torch

I have a *custom* LSTM `pytorch` model in C++. After training I save the model using

```
torch::save(lstmNetwork, 'model.pt');
```

where `lstmNetwork` is `std::shared_ptr<LSTMNetwork>`;

```
class LSTMNetwork : public torch::nn::Module {
public:
  LSTMNetwork(const torch::nn::LSTMOptions &lstmOpts1,
            const torch::nn::LSTMOptions &lstmOpts2,
            const torch::nn::LinearOptions &linearOpts);
  ~LSTMNetwork();

  torch::Tensor forward(const torch::Tensor &x);

private:
  torch::nn::LSTM lstm1;
  torch::nn::LSTM lstm2;
  torch::nn::Linear linear;
};

LSTMNetwork::LSTMNetwork(const torch::nn::LSTMOptions &lstmOpts1,
                     const torch::nn::LSTMOptions &lstmOpts2,
                     const torch::nn::LinearOptions &linearOpts)
    : torch::nn::Module(),
      lstm1(register_module("lstm1", torch::nn::LSTM(lstmOpts1))),
      lstm2(register_module("lstm2", torch::nn::LSTM(lstmOpts2))),
      linear(register_module("linear", torch::nn::Linear(linearOpts))) {}

LSTMNetwork::~LSTMNetwork() {}

torch::Tensor LSTMNetwork::forward(const torch::Tensor &input) {
  torch::nn::RNNOutput lstm_out = this->lstm1->forward(input);
  lstm_out = this->lstm2->forward(lstm_out.output);
  torch::Tensor y_pred = this->linear(lstm_out.output[-1]);
  return y_pred.view({-1});
}

// .....
  torch::nn::LSTMOptions lstmOpts1(input, hidden);
  torch::nn::LSTMOptions lstmOpts2(hidden, hidden);
  lstmOpts1.layers(numLayers)
      .dropout(NetworkConstants::klsmt1DropOut)
      .with_bias(NetworkConstants::kIncludeBias);
  lstmOpts2.layers(numLayers)
      .dropout(NetworkConstants::klsmt2DropOut)
      .with_bias(NetworkConstants::kIncludeBias);

  torch::nn::LinearOptions linearOpts(hidden, output);
  linearOpts.with_bias(false);
  lstmNetwork = std::make_shared<LSTMNetwork>(lstmOpts1, lstmOpts2, linearOpts);

  torch::optim::AdamOptions opts(learningRate);
  optimizer = std::make_shared<torch::optim::Adam>(
      torch::optim::Adam(lstmNetwork->parameters(), opts));

  if (gpuAvailable) {
    lstmNetwork->to(torch::kCUDA);
  }
//....
```

I can reload the trained model in C++ without issue, using:

```
 torch::load(lstmNetwork, 'model.pt');
```

---

I have two questions related to the above snippets:

a) Is the trained model OS independent? Can I save the model on *Windows 10* and reload it on *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*?
<sub>(The application is complied on both the platforms)</sub>

b) How do I open the saved `pytorch` model ('model.pt') in python?

Following gives an error:

```
lstmModel = torch.load('model.pt')
```

**Error :** <sub>(***showing the exact model name***)</sub>

> > > > lstmModel = torch.load('stockData\BOM500570.pt') Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 187, in
> > > >         nti
> > > >             n = int(s.strip() or "0", 8) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 8: 'ZZZZZZZZ'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 2289, in next
>       tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self)   File "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 1095, in fromtarfile
>       obj = cls.frombuf(buf, tarfile.encoding, tarfile.errors)   File "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 1037, in frombuf
>       chksum = nti(buf[148:156])   File "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 189, in nti
>       raise InvalidHeaderError("invalid header") tarfile.InvalidHeaderError: invalid header
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 591, in
>   _load
>       return legacy_load(f)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 502, in
>   legacy_load
>       with closing(tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r:', format=tarfile.PAX_FORMAT)) as tar, \   File
>   "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 1591, in open
>       return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 1621, in taropen
>       return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 1484, in **init**
>       self.firstmember = self.next()   File "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 2301, in next
>       raise ReadError(str(e)) tarfile.ReadError: invalid header
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 422, in
>   load
>       return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 595,
>   in _load
>       raise RuntimeError("{} is a zip archive (did you mean to use torch.jit.load()?)".format(f.name)) RuntimeError:
>   stockData\BOM500570.pt is a zip archive (did you mean to use
>   torch.jit.load()?)

However following executes correctly:

```
lstmModel = torch.jit.load('model.pt')
```

For the latter case, I cannot use python's `forward()/ overloaded ()` function, and I'm not sure how to use the loaded model.

```
>>> lstmModel = torch.jit.load('stockData\BOM500570.pt')
>>> input = torch.arange(5)
>>> lstmModel.forward(input)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\jit__init__.py",
>   line 1585, in **getattr**
>       return super(ScriptModule, self).**getattr**(attr)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 585,
>   in **getattr**
>       type(self).**name**, name)) AttributeError: 'ScriptModule' object has no attribute 'forward'

```
>>> lstmModel(input)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541,
>   in **call**
>       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\jit__init__.py", line 1585, in
>   **getattr**
>       return super(ScriptModule, self).**getattr**(attr)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 585,
>   in **getattr**
>       type(self).**name**, name)) AttributeError: 'ScriptModule' object has no attribute 'forward'

```
>>> lstmModel

ScriptModule(
      original_name=Module
      (lstm1): ScriptModule(original_name=Module)
      (lstm2): ScriptModule(original_name=Module)
      (linear): ScriptModule(original_name=Module)
    )
```

Comment: If you say that an error occurs somwhere, could you please add the error message?

Comment: @churill Added the error message.

Comment: What does it mean you cannot use `forward`/overloaded call method? What attributes do you have on the model when loaded with `torch.jit.load`?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Updated details

Comment: Some things to consider regarding your model in C++: first of all: where is your `forward` method defined, I see only it's declaration. If it's not defined, it might fail to export the model correctly. It shouldn't matter whether your inheritance is private, public or protected, but PyTorch's example use implicit inheritance (hence private IIRC). There is no need for virtual destructor either (same for constructor), you might want to delete those. Please update your code with definition of methods and we might be able to work it out from there.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Thanks for the details. I added the original implementation and shown only the relevant part of the code. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @P0W could you solve the problem in the meantime? I have the same issue -- loading the model in C++ again is no problem but calling forward on the scriptModule in python fails.

Comment: @JanCa No couldn't solve the problem, I ended up not using python :|

Comment: Apparently what we're trying to do is not supported https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/libtorch-save-mnist-c-examples-trained-model-into-a-file-and-load-in-from-another-c-file-to-use-for-prediction/51681/11